# How i can change direction of tags in primefaces?

Tags: css, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, components

I working with primefaces3.4 & JSF2 .i want to change direction of some tags (like tieredMenu) to rtl. this change will be for all item in tag .how can I do it?
thank!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in new version of Primefaces we can set RTL direction to components.
[www.primefaces.org](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/index.xhtml)

Answer (score -1):

As i know, primefaces 3.4 doesn't support RTL. use 3.5 instead

http://blog.primefaces.org/?p=2283